# Java throws out the following exception: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Learning how to use Java `ArrayLists` it keeps throwing the following exception:

> ```
> 496cc7/packlist.java:5: error: cannot find symbol List alist = new
> ArrayList<>(); ^ symbol: class List location: class packlist 1 error
> ```

This is entirely new to me so im not sure what is actually wrong any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
class packlist {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    List <String> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    alist.add("Mark");
    alist.add("William");
    alist.add("John");
    alist.add("Dave");
    alist.add("James");
    System.out.println("The items of alist are: " + alist);
    Collections.reverse(alist);
    System.out.println("The reversed items of alist are: " + alist);
  }
}
```

the expected result is the contents of the `ArrayList`, but in reverse i am getting the error above relating to line 5

Comment: You're importing Collection but not List.  You may have mean Collection<String> list = ... or perhaps forgot to add import java.util.List;  

_READ_ the error message - while they're not always clear especially when initially learning java - it is telling you what's at issue here.  The java compiler isn't aware of what the List class is.  This implies that it's either mispelled or there is a missing import.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: thanks for the clarification dude! ive been noticing a trend with the exercises im being given to complete where the first exercise is given to me as a code block that is relatively simple but the optional ones are covering things i haven't yet been taught (this optional exercise appeared right after a brief introduction to ArrayList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
import java.util.List;
```

and write

```
List<String> alist = new ArrayList<>();
//  ^
//  `-- no blank here
```

If you don't want to import `List`, use

```
ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: the requirements of the assesment is to use ArrayList and Collections explicitly

Comment: im guessing the course provider didn't think to specify that i would need 'import java.util.List' as this is an optional exercise and asks for use of ArrayList and Collections only ah well importing java.util.List fixed it (i find it odd that on the first part of the exercise it didn;t throw a single error regarding this)